# python filter string to return a list

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to filter a given sentence and extract all the string which are surrounded by single quotation marks and return a list.

For example, sample input:

```
"Welcome to 'Jungle', is a song by American rock band 'Guns N Roses' released in 1987."
```

Output:

```
['Jungle', 'Guns N Roses']
```

Explanation:
String - `"Jungle"` is surrounded by single quotation marks, so we need to pick this. Similarly - `Guns N Roses`. So the output is having 2 strings in its list. Another sample input:

```
"How are (you, doing today)"
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Explanation:
We do not have anything between single quotations so this returns empty list.
I tried using split function to split by single quotation, but realised that is not the right approach. Can you please help me how to do this in python?

Comment: You can use `regex` to parse the string and get the required substring.

Comment: `, is a song by American rock band ` is also surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex --> `re.findall`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "Welcome to 'Jungle', is a song by American rock band 'Guns N Roses' released in 1987."
print(re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['Jungle', 'Guns N Roses']
```

Comment: Even `re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", s)` would have worked !

Comment: @pistol2myhead. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way as well. This is the simplest programming way without using any library. You can give it a try:

```
full_string = input("Enter String: ")
quoted_strings = []

start = 0
quoted_string = ""
for letter in full_string:
    if letter == "'" and start == 0:
        start = 1
    elif letter == "'" and start == 1:
        quoted_strings.append(quoted_string)
        quoted_string = ""
        start = 0
    elif start == 1:
        quoted_string += letter
    else:
        pass

print("Entered Full String: " + full_string)
print("Quoted Strings: ", quoted_strings)
```

Although an answer is accepted just did for fun. Happy Coding !

Comment: Thanks for alternate approach

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, best approach when using regex is to avoid being "greedy".

```py
import re
a = "'Jungle', is a song by American rock band 'Guns N Roses'"]
re.findall(r"'(.+?)'", a)
```

This will look for a word surrounded by quotations. e.g. it will skip empty quotations.
If you'd like to include empty quotations, use * instead of +.

We're using '?' to make the search less greedy.